# RobotFramework-Oracle DB Connection issue-2

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB in Robot Frameowork, I am facing an issue.find the details.
Error info:
15:26:34.601 INFO Connecting using : cx_Oracle.connect(database=KIDS, user=St1_User, password=M...., host=st-kids..oss.abb.com, port=1581)

15:26:34.692 FAIL TypeError: 'database' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

If I remove the "Database" from Keyword then getting below error 
"NoSectionError: No section: 'default'"
   Below is the command used in the Test Case

Connect To Database    cx_Oracle     kIDS    St1_User    M....    st-kids.oss.abb.com    1581

Please help.

Comment: I forgot to inform, I am using    DatabaseLibrary to connect to the DB

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword `Connect To Database Using Custom Params`

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    ${connection string}
```

and as `${connection_string}`:

`user='${user}',password='${password}',dsn='${host}:${port}/${service_name}'`